# How do find out where the app saved my mutable bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I'm working on a meme generator.  Right now, I'm trying upload a photo from my device, to put captions on the photo through `Canvas` and save the new bitmap to my device's "Gallery" app by creating a new folder in it.  This is  my attempt:

```
public void createBitmapAndSave(ImageView img){
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable());
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        String topText = topTextView.getText().toString();
        String bottomText = bottomTextView.getText().toString();

        canvas.drawText(topText, 0, 0, paint);
        canvas.drawText(bottomText, 50, 50, paint);

        File file;

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        file = new File(path, "Meme" + ".jpg");

        try{
            OutputStream stream = null;

            stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
        }catch (IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

    }
```

And I'm calling the method in my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
private BroadcastReceiver listener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent ) {
            String data = intent.getStringExtra("DATA");
            Toast.makeText(context, data + " received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            createBitmapAndSave(imageView);
        }
    };
```

At the moment, I'm not even sure if the editing or the saving of the bitmap even worked because I couldn't find it anywhere in my app's folders.

**UPDATE**

I've found the issue.  I decided to place a toast message inside the try/catch block to see if the stream is working at all because before it was outside the try/catch block and I'd see it at each run.  This is what I did:

```
public void createBitmapAndSave(ImageView img){
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable());
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        String topText = topTextView.getText().toString();
        String bottomText = bottomTextView.getText().toString();

        canvas.drawText(topText, 0, 0, paint);
        canvas.drawText(bottomText, 50, 50, paint);

        File file;

        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();
        file = new File(path, "Meme" + ".jpg");

        try{
            OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (IOException e){ e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Now, I don't see the toast message at all.  It seems like the stream is not even working properly but I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: Just log/print `path` and follow that path in your phone's folder

Comment: @BachVu It just says `storage/emulated/0` but I don't have an "emulated" file in my device folders.

Comment: It means the root path of your device. For example, in some phone it means `Internal Storage`

Comment: use `MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage()` static method for inserting new image

Comment: @BachVu Yea I understand that but it still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: did you use `insertImage`? if so, what does it return?

Comment: @pskink Where do I use `insertImage` and why?

Comment: why? you want to: `"[...] and save the new bitmap to my device's "Gallery" app"` - this is what `insertImage` is doing

Comment: @pskink Could you elaborate more if you don't mind?  How does it save it to my device's "Gallery" app?

Comment: it simply uses `ContentResolver` for inserting a new entry into `MediaStrore`, more details [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java#L978)

Comment: @pskink Check my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();` 
it will store your file in private storage that is not visible to user.

use `File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory is visible to all apps, getExternalFilesDir is not. But he should use getExternalStorageDirectory().path not toString()

Comment: @TakeInfo.  I did `File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);` so I can spot it in the DCIM folder but the Toast message reads `storage/emulated/0/DCIM` and there is nothing in the DCIM folder.

Comment: have you add  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> permission in menifest file ?

Comment: @TakeInfo Yep and the problem persists.  Nothing in the `DCIM` folder